# Why is Spring Initializr spelled initializr instead of initializer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just started learning spring and while going to site https://start.spring.io/ I found that the spring people have spelled initializer as initializr. I was wondering whether it was random or is their a reason behind it.

Comment: It will be hard to answer such question unless the creator/founder is here.

Comment: Obivously to save 1 Byte per word.

Comment: An answer from the person who made a decision is considered sufficiently non-opinion-based.

Comment: @chrylis I agree that the close reason is probably not the correct one, but this is not a programming question, and I don't think this belongs on Stack Overflow. Sadly, there isn't such reason (unless a custom one is defined explaining why it's off-topic).

Comment: @g00glen00b It's unquestionably about a programming tool.

Comment: @chrylis You're right, but it should be "a practical, answerable problem that's unique to software development" according to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and in this case, it isn't practical, nor unique to software development, and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was inspired by http://www.initializr.com/ (which is maybe slightly different in intent, but fills a similar niche).

Comment: (But saving a byte is a good suggestion.)